# Query function in Java, return a list of all values from single column

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to write a function that returns all old_password values in a table for a specific user.
However, I don't know how to format it properly.

```
public List<String> fetchPasswordHistory(int userId) {
        String query = "SELECT NEW_PASSWORD FROM PASSWORD_HISTORY WHERE USER_ID = ?";
        List<String> strLst  = jdbcTemplate.query(query,new RowMapper<String>() {
            @Override
            public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return rs.getString(3);
            }
        }, userId);

        if ( strLst.isEmpty() ) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return strLst;
        }
    }
```

This will give the top 3 strings in the table. I want it to return every value that is generated from this query.
and then I am going to compare the user's pending new password with all the old passwords in the DB so the user does not repeat passwords.

Also, if the query returns nothing, it breaks.
Any help?

Comment: I suggest that returning null instead of an empty list is broken behaviour.

Comment: is it NPE at `if ( strLst.isEmpty() )` ? if so do it that way `if ( null == strList || strLst.isEmpty() )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, this query should fail because within mapRow method, you are asking for the 3-rd column of the current row. But in the "select" statement, you only obtain one column. So, you should write rs.getString(1) (it's not zero-based, so 1 will return the first column's value).

And, as far as I can see, you don't actually limit the result to 3 rows. You'll get all the rows for the query. mapRow will be executed for every row and you'll extract the list of passwords.

Comment: Ok, how should I format it if I want every single New_password value associated with that user ID?